# Ecto inserted_at, how to get only part of the date?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am starting to lear Elixir - Phoenix, coming from Rails, and I am loving it.
I have a problem with the date I get from Ecto: I need to display only the day from the auto-generated inserted_at. I also try to achieve this with Timex and timex_ecto plugin, with no luck for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pattern match on the result of [Ecto.DateTime.to_erl/1](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.DateTime.html#to_erl/1):

```
iex(4)> {{_, _, day}, _} = Ecto.DateTime.to_erl(date) 
{{2016, 1, 5}, {16, 49, 19}}

iex(5)> day
5
```

If you want to use timex, once you have a result in the erlang datetime format (`{{y, m, d}, {h, m, s}}`) you can use [Timex.Date.from/1](http://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.Date.html#from/1)

Comment: I tried pattern matching, but it is still new for me, with your answer, I start to understanding it. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I usually use calendar dependency (add to mix file) and then 
given a date from your database like date_from_db="2016-01-08T00:14:49"  you can do something like:

```
{:ok, date, _} =  date_from_db |> Calendar.NaiveDateTime.Parse.iso8601
date.day
```

Comment: Thanks for this solutions. Finding the right dependencies is hard for now in this new and growing community.